# Mailchimp 3.0 - Create campaign with interests - wrong number of selected members

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I created a new campaign using interests. Creation is ok but when checking the campaign on Mailchimp, the number of selected members is 0 (but this is wrong). If I open the recipients tab and go back to the confirm tab (without modifying anything in recipients), then the number of selected members is correct and campaign can be sent.

Is there something special to be done to get the right number of selected members?

Thx in advance!

Edit: I am using 2 different interests group for this campaign. If I only use one, it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Is the number of selected members only wrong via API call result? Or is it also incorrect on the Mailchimp dashboard?

Comment: Both. In fact, I have discovered that it does not take into account the interests group if I do it in one step. If I do create the campaign and then update it by adding the interests group, it's working.